# Bootstrap file browser change content with data attribute

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change the text on a bootstrap file browser with a data attribute like the following but it just shows whitespace:

HTML

```
<label className="custom-file">
        <input onChange={props.onChangeFileBrowser} id="files" type="file" className="custom-file-input "/>
            <span className="custom-file-control" data-content="Test Content"></span>
    </label>
```

CSS

```
.custom-file-control:lang(en)::after {
content: attr(data-content) !important;
}
```

Note: It works when setting the content directly in the stylesheet!

Comment: Why not just update the content of the span when you update the attribute? Adding in the css step seems to be extra work that only serves to complicate things.

Comment: How does the `onChangeFileBrowser` function look like?